# No Mono option in Windows for microphone

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone

I have an XLR microphone plugged into a Presonus Audiobox iTwo USB audio interface.

When I use the mic in Windows, it only plays out of the left channel.

Every post I have found online describes one of two solutions:

1. Convert the signal to Mono in whatever DAW you use
2. Go into recording devices in Windows > properties > change from 2 channel to 1 channel.

Here's my problem - I'm not using a DAW, or even recording my mic. If I was, I'd have no issue. My problem is that I want to use the mic to communicate via desktop applications such as games, discord etc.

So, it seems solution #2 is the way to achieve that. However, when I try to do that, the only available options are 2 channel.

I have tried using the drivers installed automatically via windows, still only 2 channel appears in the dropdown. I've tried going to the presonus website and downloading their drivers, all this does is add more 2 channel options and still no 1 channel options appear in the dropdown.

I've tried everything, including a full wipe and reinstallation of windows (desperate I know)

At this point I'm out of ideas, and can't find anyone online solving this problem.

I have identified some models of usb audio interface whose drivers seem to include the 1 channel option I need in Windows, but I refuse to believe that's the only solution.

Please God someone help me. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

In my case installing additional vendor software enabled solution #2 with "mono" option for my XLR mic input (using Focusrite device). Generic driver was forced to be stereo as well.

Previously used various virtual mic software as a workaround (Voicemeeter, EqualizerAPO, etc), but it was not as convinient.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).